# jquery full calendar add events dynamically using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, twig

i'm trying to use the jQuery full calendar and i must set events dynamically for results that i get from database , so i use data atrribute to set values and after that i would display it in the calender.
here is my html twig :

```
 {%  for i in suivilabo %}
 <div id="calendar" class="loopindex" data-index={{ loop.index }} 
 data-date="{{ i.futuredate|date('Y-m-d') }}</div>
 {%  endfor %}
```

And here is my js code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [

$('.loopindex').each(function() {

    {title:'INR laboratoire',start:$('.loopindex').data('date'), allDay: true},
});


    ]
});


}
```

);

Comment: you cannot have same id for all records!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you doing now doesn't make any sense, you are assuming that `$('.loopindex').each(function() {` will return a valid object and print/pass that object towards the array `events` which is not the deal (and it's even not correct syntaxily)

What you need to do instead is to create an array before initiating the calendar, e.g.

```
var dates = [];
$('div[data-date]').each(function() {
    dates.push({title:'INR laboratoire',start: $(this).data('date'), allDay: true});
});
```

This new array you can then pass towards the `event` attribute of the calendar e.g.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: dates,
});
```

Answer (score -1):

simply change the id to class

```
<div class="calendar loopindex"  ...
```

and then

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
```

Comment: global-dashboard_general_6.js:16 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : here => {title:'INR laboratoire',start:$('.loopindex').data('date'), allDay: true},

Comment: swapping id with class shouldn't give you syntax error.

Comment: While this is true, this won't solve OP's problem as he has a flaw in his code other than misusing the `id`